# How can I change my desktop background based on external event?

Tags: catalina, desktop, wallpaper

I would like to change desktop background based on plugged/non-plugged, day of the week, month, and so on. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Depending on your specific needs some launchd scripts could work, or some clever Keyboard Maestro macros (which, despite its name, also supports non-key triggers)